# Arpwatch - no email

Tags: networking

Im fairly new to Ubuntu and I decided to try and get arpwatch up and running so I can monitor my network network. After following the directions at http://aimlinux.com/blog/?p=56 I am not getting any email notifications. Sorry thats all I have to go off of right now. The service seems to be running and i think it is seeing devices on the network, but i get no notification

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see the guide was written in jan of 2009 so it could be a bit out of date so I tracked down a more up to date how to Here

[Send-only Mail Server with Exim on Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick)](http://library.linode.com/email/exim/send-only-mta-ubuntu-10.10-maverick)

I am not sure whether there have been any changes.

Hope this helps